# Storing Data from Google Places API to create Recent search history

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I have been going through the Google Places API and to make optimum use of the API in my app, I need clarity on their Terms of Service regarding Google places API.

I am working on cab sharing android application. My use case is to search location by using google autocomplete search api and store it in local database for show in recent search history like in google map application. And second use case is to store favourite locations (e.g. Home address, work address etc.) like same in google map application.

I want to know, is this ok to store google place api data for these use cases? Google's terms of usage are not very clear, so it would be great if someone can clarify this.

[Click for eference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25oWt.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As per [Google Maps Specific Terms 3.2.3 (a)](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#:~:text=Misusing%20the%20Services.-,(a)%C2%A0%C2%A0No%20Scraping,-.%20Customer%20will%20not), you cannot store Google Maps Content outside the services, and save addresses.

Comment: You can only cache location (`lat,lngs`) values from the Places API for up to 30 consecutive calendar days, after which your must delete the cached latitude and longitude values, as per [Google Maps Specific Terms for Places API](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms#:~:text=non%2DGoogle%20map.-,5.4%20Caching,-.%20Customer%20can%20temporarily).

Please comply to the aforementioned terms to avoid project suspension.

Comment: @Beth Thanks for reply. It is clear about we can save lat, long for 30 days and save placeId forever. But what about place addresses? can we save them? because place addresses are public text and they will use many times in application.

Comment: Beth already stated above that "you cannot store Google Maps Content outside the services, and save **addresses**."